# RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo: java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: android, mysql, web-services, apache-axis, listview-selector

Hi I am trying display the data from mysql into android listview by using web services axis2.
When I run my app getting the following exeption.
Here is the Logcat details

```
12-28 21:20:45.180: E/AndroidRuntime(406): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-28 21:20:45.180: E/AndroidRuntime(406): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.kbj/com.kbj.Invitation}: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-28 21:20:45.180: E/AndroidRuntime(406):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
12-28 21:20:45.180: E/AndroidRuntime(406):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
12-28 21:20:45.180: E/AndroidRuntime(406):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
12-28 21:20:45.180: E/AndroidRuntime(406):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
12-28 21:20:45.180: E/AndroidRuntime(406):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-28 21:20:45.180: E/AndroidRuntime(406):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
12-28 21:20:45.180: E/AndroidRuntime(406):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
12-28 21:20:45.180: E/AndroidRuntime(406):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-28 21:20:45.180: E/AndroidRuntime(406):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
12-28 21:20:45.180: E/AndroidRuntime(406):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
12-28 21:20:45.180: E/AndroidRuntime(406):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
12-28 21:20:45.180: E/AndroidRuntime(406):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-28 21:20:45.180: E/AndroidRuntime(406): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-28 21:20:45.180: E/AndroidRuntime(406):  at com.kbj.Invitation.onCreate(Invitation.java:49)
12-28 21:20:45.180: E/AndroidRuntime(406):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
12-28 21:20:45.180: E/AndroidRuntime(406):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
12-28 21:20:45.180: E/AndroidRuntime(406):  ... 11 more
12-28 21:20:50.690: I/Process(406): Sending signal. PID: 406 SIG: 9
```

Here are the my functions

**1. retrieveData in Web Services class**

```
public ArrayList<InvitePlayerDetails> retrievePlayer(String userName){

    Connection conn=null;
    PreparedStatement stmt=null;

      ResultSet result = null; 
      String retrievedUserName = "";
      //Boolean b = false;
     // String retrievedPassword = "";
      ArrayList<InvitePlayerDetails> playersList = new ArrayList<InvitePlayerDetails>();

    try{


       conn = Util.getConnection();
       stmt =  conn.prepareStatement("SELECT kbj_username FROM kbj_registration");
       result = stmt.executeQuery();
       System.out.println(result);

       while(result.next()){
        retrievedUserName = result.getString("kbj_username");
        System.out.println(retrievedUserName);
        InvitePlayerDetails p1 = new InvitePlayerDetails(retrievedUserName, false);
       // ArrayList<InvitePlayerDetails> playersList = new ArrayList<InvitePlayerDetails>(retrievedUserName, b);
        playersList.add(p1);

        System.out.println("PlayerListAdded" + playersList);
    }


      }
      catch(SQLException e)
      {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }

      finally
        {           
        Util.CloseDbResources(result, stmt, conn);

        }
return playersList;
}
}
```

**Here is my android activity function..**

public class Invitation extends Activity
{

```
private final String NAMESPACE = "http://ws.kbj.com";
private final String URL = "http://10.0.2.2:8085/WS_KBJ/services/Kbj_WebService?wsdl";
private final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://ws.kbj.com/retrievePlayer";
private final String METHOD_NAME = "retrievePlayer";


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.invitation);

    final TextView userName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.CurPlayername);
    userName.setText(getIntent().getExtras().getString("UserName"));

    final Button fbBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.fbButton);
    final Button inviteBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.inviteBtn);
    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.invitePlayerList);  
    ArrayList<InvitePlayerDetails> playersList = new ArrayList<InvitePlayerDetails>();  


    playersList = retriveData();


    InvitePlayersBaseAdapter adapter = new InvitePlayersBaseAdapter(this, playersList);  
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);  
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {  
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int position,  
                long id) {  

        }  
    });  
    final Intent openFbOrTwLoginPage = new Intent(this, FbOrTwLogin.class);
    final Intent openNotificationPage = new Intent(this, Notification.class);
    fbBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            startActivity(openFbOrTwLoginPage);

        }
    });
    twBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            startActivity(openFbOrTwLoginPage);

        }
    });
    inviteBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            startActivity(openNotificationPage);

        }
}

public ArrayList<InvitePlayerDetails> retriveData(){
ArrayList<InvitePlayerDetails> playersList = new ArrayList<InvitePlayerDetails>();
SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
PropertyInfo unameProp =new PropertyInfo();
    unameProp.setName("userName");//Define the variable name in the web service method
    unameProp.setValue(title);//set value for userName variable
    unameProp.setType(String.class);//Define the type of the variable
    request.addProperty(unameProp);

SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

    try{
        androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
           SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();


           System.out.println("SoapPriitive:"+response);
           //status1 = Boolean.parseBoolean(response.toString());

    }
    catch(Exception e){

    }


    return playersList;
}
```

}

**and I have created one pojo class which is**

```
public class InvitePlayerDetails {


private String invitedplayerName;
private boolean ckBox;
  public InvitePlayerDetails(String invitedplayerName,boolean cb1) {  
        this.invitedplayerName = invitedplayerName;  
        this.ckBox = cb1;  
    }  

public String getInvitedplayerName() {
    return invitedplayerName;
}
public void setInvitedplayerName(String invitedplayerName) {
    this.invitedplayerName = invitedplayerName;
}
public boolean getCkBox() {
    return ckBox;
}
public void setCkBox(boolean b) {
    this.ckBox = b;
}

}
```

Please help me about this..
Tell me where is wrong in my code..
If anyone have code about displaying a data from mysql in listviews using axis2 provide here..
Sorry for my english..
Thanks in advance..

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException   at com.kbj.Invitation.onCreate(Invitation.java:49)` What is line 49 in Invitation?

Comment: Hi sir.. Invitation is the android android class main.. when i click on login button contol goes to the Invitation activity.. Here is my Login class code  btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   public void onClick(View arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    boolean status = loginAction();
    if (status == true){
     
     intent.putExtra("UserName", user_Name);
     //intent.putExtra("Content", listDescriptionString);
     startActivity(openInvitationPage);
    }else{
     result.setText("Login Failed!!");
    }
    
   }
  
  });

Comment: Please click "[edit]" to add your code to your question and indicate which line is 49. But it looks like you forgot to initialize `btnLogin`, `intent`, or `result`.

Comment: your are adding value in `intent` but passing `openInvitationPage` to `startActivity` so make sure you are using right intent for starting next activity

Comment: @Sam Hi now check it sir.. I have edited Invitation class in the code details

Comment: Hi actually intent variable was used for passing a data(username) from one activity to next activity. But both intents are totally different one is openInvitationPage and another one is only intent

Comment: @MallikarjunHampannavar It's hard just looking at that class and deciding what's line 49. So WHAT IS line 49?

Comment: @MallikarjunHampannavar That is much easier to read! I don't see where you are defining or initializing `twBtn`... Is `twBtn.setOnClickListener(...)` line 49?

Comment: The editor you're using to write the code will tell you what line 49 is in Invitation.java.

Comment: @Sam leave that twbtn this is id for another xml file.. I'm not getting where the line 49 causing the error.. playersList = retriveData(); from this statment im calling the method and storing the returned arraylist values into playerlist variable

Comment: @varevarao In my actuall code there are more comments and unwanted codes are there so I'm not getting where the 49 line statment is there.. Even I have counted the lines also but no use 49 line came under commented statements..

Comment: @MallikarjunHampannavar In Eclipse use Ctrl+L to jump to line 49. Understand that the LogCat doesn't lie. If you posted the most recent LogCat then your error is on line 49 in Invitation.java.

Comment: @Sam Yes sir Line 49 is this statement playersList = retriveData();

Answer (score 0):

You haven't indicate which line is 49, but I have a couple guesses:

```
userName.setText(getIntent().getExtras().getString("UserName"));
```

Here you don't check if `getIntent()`, `getExtras()`, or even `getString("UserName")` return null. You should make sure that each method returns valid data before trying to use it.

Also I don't see `twBtn` anywhere else:

```
twBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        startActivity(openFbOrTwLoginPage);

    }
});
```

It is not initialized or even defined...

If neither of these are on line 49, then double check your layout `invitation.xml` to make sure that *every* View that you search for with `findViewById()` is in this layout. Otherwise `findViewById()` will return null...

Comment: "If neither of these are on line 49..". Haha, if it's not even findViewById() then check line 49, you're getting a NullPointerException there. :D

Comment: @Sam Hi here is the twBtn statement final Button twBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.twButton); like this I have declared twbtn in android class and declared this id in twButton in xml file also..

Comment: @MallikarjunHampannavar It is impossible for `playersList = retriveData();` to cause a NullPointerException... Did you change Inivitation after getting those LogCat errors? Also please post `invitation.xml` in your question.

Comment: @Sam sir.. I have fixed that NullPointerExecption..My requirement is display a data from mysql into listview.. For this I am trying last 2-3 days but not get successful.. I found the code for this in google but they are in php and json. I dont knw about php and json so its bit difficult to understand those codes. Can u please suggest or provide me codes about display data from mysql into listview using axis2 web services? please sir its urgent

Comment: I'm glad you have solved the NullPointerException. But I haven't used MySQL with Android, so I'm sorry I cannot help you with that... Good luck!